# In Power BI Desktop, how do I create a hierarchy from types of measures?

Tags: hierarchy, powerbi

I have data that has columns for different types of sales, as well as a column for total sales. I'd like to create a hierarchy so I can drill into the total sales in a chart to see the product level sales. How do I enable this type of drilling without needing to transpose the data?

[image: snapshot of underlying data]

Data Columns:
hh_id   product_1   product_2   product_3   total_sales

Comment: Edit queries -> Delete "total_sales" -> select all product columns -> "Unpivot Columns"

Comment: Correct answer - that worked for me. Thanks for the response - if enter your comment under "Answer the Question" I can mark it as answered. Basically you need to treat the fields you drill on as a dimension, rather than a measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Switch to Query Editor,
- Remove "total_sales",
- Select all "product_*" columns,
- Transform -> "Unpivot Columns",
- Rename created "Attribute" and "Value" columns appropriately.